# WM_KEYUP for non-Virtual Keys (windows.h WindowProc)

Tags: c++, windows, input, msdn

I see that WindowProc can use WM_CHAR and wParam to detect character input, and I also see that WindowProc can use WM_KEYUP and wParam to detect virtual key releases. However, I would like to detect the moment that the user releases some other key (semicolon for instance). I haven't yet found the documentation for this scenario on MSDN.

How can you detect key releases in the WindowProc for keys which have no Virtual Key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All keys have a virtual key code, some of them are just not exposed through a macro. For example, a key that is asociated with a letter has a VK value of that letter's ASCII code. For a semicolon, according to [this list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes), you would use one of the OEM keys, depending on the keyboard.

As a more portable way to solve your problem, [`MapVirtualKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mapvirtualkeya) (or, for the keyboard-dependent keys, [`MapVirtualKeyEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mapvirtualkeyexa)) can be called from `WM_KEYUP` to find their associated character.